# Upper bound for $n!$

Tags: factorial

Let $a\in\mathbb{N}$. is there an upper bound be for the smallest n so that $n!>a$?

It doesn't have to be a good upper bound, just something that works.

Thanks.

Comment: See [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation).

Comment: I think $a$ would be an upper bound for such an $n$, at least for $a>2$. As you say, not a good upper bound asymptotically, but certainly an upper bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We observe that
$$
n!> 2^n \quad (n\geq 4).
$$
Indeed, for $n=4$ we have $4!=24>2^4=16$. Suppose that the inequality holds for $n=k$.
Then
$$
(k+1)!=k!(k+1)>2^k(k+1)>2^k2=2^{k+1}.
$$
Choose $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ smallest such that $2^{n_0}>a$. Then
$$
n_0=\left \lfloor{\frac{\ln(a)}{\ln(2)}}\right \rfloor+1.
$$

- If $0\leq a<1$ then the least upper bound for the smallest $n$ such that $n!>a$ is $0$.
- If $1\leq a<2$ then the least upper bound for the smallest $n$ such that $n!>a$ is $2$.
- If $2\leq a<6$ then the least upper bound for the smallest $n$ such that $n!>a$ is $3$.
- If $6\leq a<24$ then the least upper bound for the smallest $n$ such that $n!>a$ is $4$.
- If $a\geq 24$ then an upper bound for the smallest $n$ such that $n!>a$ is $n_0$.